# LLM model short in producing a successful query to satisfy the intent:

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, openai-api, large-language-model

I've compiled a small list of examples where the current LLM falls short in producing a successful query to satisfy the intent:

`intent: Is there a pattern in the query parameters that corresponds to higher latencies?
model: openai/gpt-3.5-turbo
regex_clean_query: '

```
df_filtered = df[df[''QueryParams''].notnull()]


df_filtered[''Latency_ms''] = df_filtered[''Latency_ms''].astype(float)

df_filtered[''QueryParams''] = df_filtered[''QueryParams''].apply(eval)


df_grouped = df_filtered.groupby(''QueryParams'')[''Latency_ms''].mean().reset_index()


df_sorted = df_grouped.sort_values(''Latency_ms'', ascending=False)
```

intent: Can we identify any trends in service usage over the given time period?
model: openai/gpt-3.5-turbo
regex_clean_query: '# Filter the data frame based on the given time period

```
start_date = ''2021-01-01''

end_date = ''2021-12-31''

df_filtered = df[(df[''Timestamp''] >= start_date) & (df[''Timestamp''] <= end_date)]


service_usage = df_filtered.groupby(''ServiceName'').size().reset_index(name=''UsageCount'')


service_usage = service_usage.sort_values(by=''UsageCount'', ascending=False)
```

intent: Which endpoint has the most varied latency times?
model: openai/gpt-3.5-turbo
regex_clean_query: '# Filter the dataframe to include only the required columns

```
filtered_df = df[[''Endpoint'', ''Latency_ms'']]


grouped_df = filtered_df.groupby(''Endpoint'')[''Latency_ms''].nunique()


endpoint_with_most_varied_latency = grouped_df.idxmax()
```

`

Comment: How could one answer the questions differently?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.